# How to use PyTorch Tensor.index_select()?

Tags: python, indexing, reinforcement-learning, pytorch

Currently trying to implement REINFORCE algorithm using PyTorch. I wish to be able to gather responsible outputs after having discounted the reward. Hence, given the actions memory, I create a Tensor of indexes, and try to use Tensor.index_select, but no success. Can anyone help ?

```
    rH = np.array(rH) # discounted reward
    aH = np.array(aH) # action_holder
    sH = np.vstack(np.array(sH)) # states holder

    statesTensor = Variable(torch.from_numpy(sH).type(torch.FloatTensor))
    out = model.forward(statesTensor)

    indexes = GuiltyOnes(out, aH)
    flat = out.view(1,-1)

    respos = torch.index_select(flat, 1, torch.from_numpy(indexes).type(torch.LongTensor))
```

I get the following error:

```
    return IndexSelect.apply(self, dim, index)
    RuntimeError: save_for_backward can only save input or output tensors, but argument 0 doesn't satisfy this condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case might be similar to [this one](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nn-module-using-index-select/3570), therefore, you should use a `Variable` instead:

```
i = Variable(torch.from_numpy(indexes).long())
respos = torch.index_select(flat, 1, i)
```

---

Keep in mind that pytorch error messages aren't always really accurate. In this case, it's quite misleading imo.